# Change specific row color uipicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i have the following problem: I can change the text color of the rows inside the uipicker but not the text color of the specific row i want, the picker gets all confused and a lot of text labels become blue.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    UILabel *retval = (UILabel*)view;
    if (!retval) {
        retval= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].width, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];
    }
    retval.text = [arraySubSistemasDeSaude objectAtIndex:row];
    if(pickerView == subSistemaSaudePicker) {

        if ([retval.text isEqualToString:@"Seguros de saúde"]) {

            NSLog(@"ROW=%d",row);
            [retval setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        }
        if ([retval.text isEqualToString:@"Sistemas de Saúde e Equiparados"]) {
           NSLog(@"ROW=%d",row);
       [retval setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

         if ([retval.text isEqualToString:@"Seguradoras-Acidentes de Trabalho, viação/pessoais e vida"]) {
            NSLog(@"ROW=%d",row);
            [retval setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
         }
       if ([retval.text isEqualToString:@"Empresas, associações e outras entidades"]) {
            NSLog(@"ROW=%d",row);

            [retval setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

       }


        [retval setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        retval.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

       }

    } else if(pickerView == horarioPicker) {
        retval.text =[arrayHorarios objectAtIndex:row];
        [retval setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        retval.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

    } else if(pickerView == examesPicker) {
        retval.text =[arrayExames objectAtIndex:row];
        [retval setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        retval.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

    } else if(pickerView == consultasPicker) {
        retval.text =[arrayConsultas objectAtIndex:row];
        [retval setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        retval.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

    }else {
        assert(NO);
    }
  return retval;
}
```

Sorry for my bad english,i hope i made myself clear with the question, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, you are reusing the view for each row and you are not setting the UILabel color back to black when it is not supposed to be blue.

Add this code...

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    UILabel *retval = (UILabel*)view;
    if (!retval) {
        retval= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].width, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];
    }
    [retval setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    retval.text = [arraySubSistemasDeSaude objectAtIndex:row];
    ......
```

With this, each time it pulls up a reused view it will first set the color to black.  Then the code will check for the ones you want that are blue and set them to blue.  The way you were doing it, it was setting the blue color on some of them, then when you went to reuse them you were never resetting it to black.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row       forComponent:(NSInteger)component  reusingView:(UIView *)view {

  UILabel *pickerLabel = (UILabel *)view;

  if (pickerLabel == nil) {

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 80, 32);
        pickerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
        [pickerLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
        [pickerLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [pickerLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
        [pickerLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [pickerLabel setText:@"MyTest"];

   }



   return pickerLabel;

}
```